# How to show a dialog on current Activity using Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I've develop an Android app with phonegap 2.5.0, my app need to run in background and when some event occur it will show confirm dialog on the current activity. I have looking for the solution and find android's **BroadcastReceiver**, but I don't know how to implement **BroadcastReceiver** in Phonegap, is there any plug in to implements Android Broadcast Receiver on phonegap or maybe is there better solutions to showing dialog on current activity?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out NetworkManager plugin in PhoneGap.

https://github.com/callback/callback-android/blob/master/framework/src/com/phonegap/NetworkManager.java

It uses BroadcastReceiver as a plugin